# How can I run a "background" infant loop with PHP?

Tags: php, web-applications

I am looking for a way to check if there are any new files in a directory. Can I do this live with some infant loop? When I say:

```
   <?php
        while (true) {
            $files = glob("../example/*.txt");
          $count_posts = $files !== false ? count($files) : 0;
            if ($count_posts > 0) {
                break;
            print("WE DID IT!!!!!!!");
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Three weird things happen: 1.) The page will keep loading - which I can't have 2.) It won't print "WE DID IT!!!!!!!!!" and 3.) No content will be shown until there is a new file. How can I do this?

Comment: my idea, put the inner part(with no loop) in a function, and call it once after page loads, and once with every change that can invoke this to be true or every couple of seconds (with JS)... for that you'll need to put it in a different file and access it from your file.

Comment: How could I do that? As far as accessing it from a different file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as looping through a directory to check for files use the DirectoryIterator, or if there are sub-folders the RecursiveDirectoryIterator. Your while loop will be caught in an infinite loop if the glob statement returns false or 0.

For example:

```
$iterator = new DirectoryIterator('../example');
foreach ($iterator as $path) {
  if ($path->isFile()) {
     if (strpos($path->getFilename(), '.txt') !== false) {
         print("WE DID IT!!!!!!!");
         break;
     }
}
```

Or with a recursive directory iterator..

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('../example'));
foreach ($iterator as $path) {
   ...
}
```

If you need to run this as a background task you need to use AJAX, as Ben suggests. A normal PHP request via a web page is designed to load everything and display the contents back to the page. AJAX requests are the only way to do asynchronous requests on the web. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: How can I do this with ajax? It doesn't mention it in the link.

Comment: AJAX basically works by sending asynchronous HTTP requests to the server (i.e. PHP) via JavaScript. PHP then returns something (usually a string or JSON which is a bit more flexible) and your JavaScript then does something with that (i.e. updates the HTML of the page). You can read a tutorial on how to get started with jQuery which includes a section on using AJAX with PHP at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Rate_me:_Using_Ajax

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that you can't do it without using sockets and/or Javascript. PHP won't return any information until the entire page is completely loaded, in this instance nothing will display until the break clause is called.

I'd have a seperate script that checks for new files in the folder that's polled by javascript via setTimeout and AJAX every X seconds.

Comment: PHP can return data if you use the flush() command and the server isn't buffering content. http://example.preinheimer.com/flush.php